# Why was this answer treated as spam?

Tags: discussion

A new user posted this answer: [What are some waterproof materials that meet my criteria for folding origami stars and cranes eggs?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/10378/8251).  For people who can't see the deleted post:

> I have folded origami tesselations from parchment paper. It's not completely waterproof, but hanging in a window I think it could afford a few raindrops without losing its shape. I love origami,  need to get back into it. Beautiful!![image][image]

The criteria in the question (and the question states that all criteria do not necessarily have to be met):

> Criteria (in order of importance):
>
> - Waterproof (enough to withstand some splashes of rain if the window is ever left open accidentally)  *[The author states they believe the recommended medium would hold up to this.]*
> - "pliable" enough to fold but firm/thick enough to keep the shape of the origami *[the recommended medium does this.]*
> - Come in long strips of about 5/16 - 1/2 inch wide *[Trivial to cut strips with any paper cutter.]*
> - Able to come in multiple colors *[It is available in colors.]*
> - Relatively inexpensive *[It's less expensive than some of the recommendations in other answers.]*

This answer appears to have been posted in good faith.  The quality of the post is not low (attempts to answer the question, recommends a medium that can be appropriate for origami, meets the criteria in the question, and shows images of the medium used for origami, demonstrating its suitability).  It does end with a superfluous comment that should be edited out.

It's a matter of opinion how good a solution this is.  For readers who think it isn't a good solution, the way to handle that is downvotes and comments.  Deletion is not supposed to be used for posts that attempt an actual answer but provides what some people think is a poor solution.

Beyond deletion, treating a post as spam or abusive carries a serious penalty for the poster.  There is nothing abusive about this post, and no visible evidence that it is spam.  This appears to be an attempted serious answer by a new user.  It isn't clear why it was treated as spam (and I believe posts deleted by a moderator cannot be undeleted by the community, so simply voting it into the undelete review queue won't work).

Comment: Reverted, thanks for pointing it out. My mistake, as you probably figured: I wondered how I as a mod could put it in a review queue (in my opinion it is low quality, as the answer doesn't really make sense for the question what waterproof materials are possible for origami, and the photos seemed to be completely unrelated) without having my vote weigh more heavily than that of others. Why I - apparently - flagged it as spam, I do not know. I have been unreasonably distracted lately, so I fear that is also having its effect on my moderation. I will tread more carefully.

Comment: @Joachim, some moderators create a second account and post enough answers on it to build enough rep to have some privileges, like review queues.  Such "sock puppets" are not supposed to exist, at least for regular users due to their potential for mischief like irregular voting.  But moderators can have a legitimate need, like testing that requires seeing what a regular user sees or putting something in a review queue for community decision.  So I assume it's either blanket allowed for moderators, or there's a mechanism to get it OK'ed, and those moderators are careful not to abuse it.

Comment: @Joachim, BTW, moderators have lives, too.  Don't burn yourself out thinking you need to do everything and be everywhere all the time.  :-)